# How do I make Duplicate action RESTful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a very simple Rails application that performs regular CRUD operations on an object (Path), this all fits nicely in the REST philosophy of Rails.  Now however, I need to add a "Duplicate" feature (i.e. create new path from existing path).  I have added it as an (RESTfull) action in my path_controller, so far so good (maybe not completely in line with the REST philosophy but I am not a purist).

Now I want to extend the functionality so that the users can choose to either create a completely new path from an existing one *or* copy the existing path to another, already existing path (duplicating its children).  This means I am going to need a few extra Views:

- one that allows them to pick Option 1 (Create New Object) or Option 2 (Duplicate to existing Object).
- If they choose Option 2, I need another View that lets them then pick the path they want to copy to.

Each of these views needs a corresponding action, and it is here that I am struggling as to where this all fits in REST.

This is a fairly simple example but as my UIs get more complex, I always run into this issue: How do I make my actions I need for my UI fit in REST controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new collection route to your resource:

```
resources :paths do
  collection do
    get :duplicate
  end
end
```

and add a duplicate method to your paths controller and views for it...

now you can access and address specifi routes for your users choice.